# console.log statements in react component test files not working when using react-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, create-react-app

I created a react app using create-react-app with typescript and trying to console log a couple of things from the test file but it's not working.

[This](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript) is the tutorial I followed to set up create react app with typescript. I just added a console.log statement in the App.test.tsx file that comes with the setup and it didn't work.

***It worked fine when I removed the 2 lines of code that used ReactDOM***

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "testing2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "24.0.11",
    "@types/node": "11.12.0",
    "@types/react": "16.8.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "typescript": "3.3.4000"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

**App.test.tsx** *(doesn't work)*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  console.log('hello thereeeeeeee');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

**App.test.tsx** *(works)*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  console.log('hello thereeeeeeee');
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  // ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  // ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

console.log statement is supposed to print. But it is not printing. The test is passing but the console statement is not printing *when I use ReactDOM in the test*